# Working with 3 GB file

Tags: r

I have a 3.8 GB text file ~5 million rows and I want to run an anova on some columns - WH.

When I read the text file it gives and error:

```
d<-read.table("test.txt", header= TRUE, sep="|")
head(d)
dim(d)
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 31.2 Mb

How Can I work with this data?

I am on Windows with 8GB of physical memory and using 32 bit R with memory.limit(0 = 3583)

Comment: Are you using 32 bit R instead of 64? What is the output of memory.limit() ?

Comment: I am using 32 bir R with memory.limit(0 = 3583

Comment: How many columns? I suspect you don't have adequate RAM. If you only need certain columns you could read in only the ones you need.

Comment: You should definitely install the 64 bit version of R, but I would also check to make sure that you really want to have a vector that big...

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comment above, you could use `data.table::fread` with its `select` parameter to read in selected columns from your file. It's also a lot faster than `read.table` and shows progress. If you want a data.frame rather than data.table you can use the `data.table = FALSE` parameter.

You really should be using 64 bit R though anyway.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html max 4 GB for 32 bit processes and in practice max vector size around 2 GB on 32 bit R.

Comment: what are max sizes for 64 bit?

Comment: As per the link above, 8TB is the total limit. The limit per vector is more to do with the number of elements. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/LongVectors.html for versions of R >= 3. Prior to that the limit was 2^31 - 1 elements. That's true for matrices as well since internally a matrix is a vector with a dim attribute.